# Are Transactions and Receipts 1-to-1?

Tags: transactions, database, receipts

Ethereum maintains an Transaction Trie and a Receipts Trie and I'm trying to visualize how that data would be contained in a relational database.

I believe both Tries would have a primary key of `transaction_hash`, and I don't believe there is any other data duplicated between Tries nor any other unique identifier in either to use as a PK or FK between a `transactions` table and `receipts` table.

All that is to say, in a relational database would both Tries just live in a single table?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to relate Merkel Patricia Tree with relational Database. 
In Go Ethereum  Merkel Patricia tree uses level db which is the key-value pair database. 
Block header contains receipt root and transaction root, which can be used to lookup actual node of the tree from level db.

To answer your question, I don't think both tries have same key i.e. transaction_hash. It's simply not possible, level db can't store two entries with the same key.

Keys are calculated by this formula -

key/root = sha3(rlp_encode(node)), where node is also key, value pair.

I strongly recommend you to read about Merkel Patricia tree for [here](https://wanderer.github.io/ethereum/nodejs/code/2014/05/21/using-ethereums-tries-with-node/)
 and [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/11/15/merkling-in-ethereum/)

[image]

Comment: Well I mean, the method to identify a given receipt belongs to a given transaction must be representable in some fashion as a "unique key", assuming transations+receipts are really 1-to-1